# I need to generate random profile pictures for my game

Tags: javascript, image-processing

I'm creating a poker game where there will be computer players. I need to generate fake computer rendered face pictures in JS preferably. I have found something called ThreeJS (https://threejs.org) but it animates 3d rendered people. I don't know if I can use it just for the face. Can someone give me hints? Maybe I can program it myself. I need random faces.

And how can I iconify a face picture? I think it's an option worth considering since my website is full of icons. do I have to do face segmentation? please help.

Answer (score 1):

### Maybe you need Machine Learning model.

I suggest you to make it on Python. You need to get a lot of faces... And train a [model](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Face+generator+ai).
Here are some links to Youtube(how someone made it):

1. [CodeParade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4VAkrUNLKSo)
2. [Carykh](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTlXEJjfsQU)

Recommend to search about CNN, TensorFlow and Keras.

### You also can just have pictures of real people.

It can be made by **API**. If you don't know any API, you can use **web-scraper**. Like get faces from social-media using bot. Maybe it's good option.

By both options you may need faces stock. May be helpful [famous birthdays](https://www.famousbirthdays.com/most-popular-people.html) site.

---

You can also take a look at **faces.js**.

---

And can be helpful [ThisPersonDoesNotExist](https://thispersondoesnotexist.com), but I do not recommend it if you need photos that user can watch closely. There can be other objects, which generated not really good. Like 3 eyes on someone.

Comment: if you need stock face photos, this site might help: https://www.thispersondoesnotexist.com